# Settled context-meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

Attitude - a settled way of thinking or feeling about someone or something, typically one that is reflected in a person's behavior.

Settle here means:
a) adopt a more steady style of life
b) accept to

Wich one should I choose?

Comment: [correction: which] Not a more steady style of life. A more settled lifestyle. Please look up the word settle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think either of those definitions applies. In this context, 'settled' means stable or relatively fixed. A 'settled way of thinking' implies that someone's ideas have continuity in their current format, i.e. that it is likely they will be the same or similar without a significant cause of change. It doesn't mean that the ideas cannot change, just that they are generally stable.

Comment: If someone wants a reference: [3 a: to become fixed, resolved, or established](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/settled)